# How to write arcs directly in G-code?

Tags: g-code, cad

How can I write G-code for a triangle without sharp tips?

[image: Example of required triangle]

I want to generate the corners manually, rather than using a slicer to generate them, just to know how it is done.

Comment: your question is extremely terse. Do you want to generate the corners manually or do you want to understand how a slicer maces them? How a CAD does them?!

Comment: With lots and lots of tiny segments.

Comment: @towe True, even if you use G2/G3

Answer (score 6):

First, convert the given measurements into a sketch...

[image: Sketched out dimensions]

### G-code shenanigans

we actually have the printer do circles.. let's plot that out...

[image: Plotted all start-ends and centers]

Using that, it's easy to write the G-code using the Documentation for [G1](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G000-G001.html) and [G2](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G002-G003.html). You'll have to add the E values to extrude something along the paths, but your sketch would turn into this path:

```
G92 X0 Y0 ; the current position is now (0,0) on the XY
G90 ;Abolute mode for everything...
M83 ;...but for the E-argument, so you can just put the length into the extrusions that are to be done
G0 X10.66 Y2 
G2 R5 X6.33 Y9.5 ; Alternate: G3 I0 J5 X6.33 Y9.5
G1 X45.66 Y77.638 
G2 R5 X54.33 Y77.638 ; Alternate: G3 I4.33 Y-2.5 X54.33 Y77.638
G1 93.67 Y9.5
G2 R5 X89.33 Y2 ; Alternate: G3 I-4.33 Y-2.5 X89.33 Y2
G1 X10.66 Y2
G0 X0 Y0
G91 ; return to relative coordinates
```

**This code has to be prefixed by a move to where you want to start the pattern** and will **not** know if you move it off the build plate, so keep 100 mm X and 87 mm in Y of the allowable build plate. It will end exactly where you started it.

### Iterative approach

In many uses of g-code, *rounded* corners are actually n-gons with a very high number n. then we only need `G1` and can easily calculate the length of the stretches and fill in the G1. We need to iterate down to somewhat circular...

Let's start iterating with n=3 aka a triangle, which gives a direct line over the corner gives this:

[image: Iteration 1]

going to n=6 (hexagon) follows the curve a lot better...

[image: Iteration 2]

going to n=12 looks almost round on a larger scale...

[image: Iteration 3]

and when we reach n=24, we are pretty close to the circle..

[image: iteration 4]

And as we go above n=6, we also get easier math for the corners, as we always get the same lengths of movement along X and Y just swapped around due to symmetry.

With all these stretches defined, we could start to work in *relative* coordinates easily, again without E, and only for the bottom left corner:

```
G0 X10.66 Y2 
G1 X-1.294 Y0.17
G1 X-1.206 Y0.5
G1 X-1.036 Y0.795
G1 X-0.795 X1.036
G1 X-0.5 Y1.206
G1 X-0.17 Y1.294
G1 X0.17 Y1.294
G1 X0.5 Y1.036
...
```

Comment: Killer explanation ... love the graphics, which completely help the understanding. +1

Comment: Beautifully illustrated, but it is responsive to the question  The question seemed to be about writing arcs in g-code, rather than how one could simulate arcs with line segments.

Answer (score 5):

Marlin has `G2` (clockwise arc) and `G3` (counterclockwise arc) commands that could be used to do this. [You can find detailed documentation for the command here.](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G002-G003.html)

Basically, you can use

> G2 R1 X5 Y5

to draw a (clockwise) arc from the current position to $(X,Y)=(5,5)$ with a radius of $1$.

So, your rounded triangle could be drawn with 3 straight line moves and 3 arc moves. Figuring out the exact coordinates for each move would be a quite challenging geometry exercise, as you'd need to know where the straight line portion of each side ends and the rounded portion starts.

Comment: it's an easy exercise with a CAD though

Comment: Do note that in the firmware support for G2/G3 must be enabled in the firmware, e.g. in Marlin by definition of `#define ARC_SUPPORT` in the Configuration_adv.h file. Also, shouldn't your printer board must have a sufficient capable processor to process the calculations for this option?

Comment: @0scar circles are rather usual in CNC commands and most printer boards can double for those. I assume you might want to use the IJ argument instead of the R Argument though.

Comment: @Trish The question specifies the G-code must be created "manually". I'm not sure if using CAD still counts as manual.